# How can I filter out values from a text file in python

Tags: python

I am running capa to analyze files , I am redirecting output into a text file
I only want unique features from the text file and I want to add it to a new list
I have specifed things I do not want  in a list named values
I want to compare the details of file_details:

```
['md5                     318271d61f4c88ccce4384ecea22807b', 'sha1                    2396ad920f108dad605e9d7664e38bae0ece685c', 'sha256                  3cc170a25027b48537aca361ed718e77ee86d028203e8a710e71f1136b5c674a', 'path                    /home/zakaria/code/malware/Backdoor.Win32.BlackHole.asva_e7e4.exe', 'timestamp               2023-09-19 11:47:28.203754', 'capa version            6.1.0', 'os                      windows', 'format                  pe', 'arch                    i386', 'extractor               VivisectFeatureExtractor', 'base address            0x400000', 'rules                   /tmp/_MEIQJyrc9/rules', 'function count          4', 'library function count  0', 'total feature count     21333', '', 'decompress data using aPLib', 'namespace    data-manipulation/compression', 'description  detects decompression function of library aPLib', 'scope        function', 'matches      0x77470B', '', '', '']
```

and add the filtered_values in a list :

the new list should be ['decompress data using aPLib' ,........] etc,

however my code doesnt seem to filter out the values i do not want  can someone please guide me to the right direction
code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import csv

# values i do not need
values = ['md5', 'sha1', 'sha256', 'path', 'timestamp', 'capa version', 'os', 'format', 'arch', 'extractor', 'base address', 'rules', 
          'function count', 'library function count', 'total feature count', 'namespace', 'scope', 'matches', '0x',
          '(internal) packer file limitation', 'Packed samples have often been obfuscated to hide their logic.',
          'capa cannot handle obfuscation well. This means the results may be misleading or incomplete.',
          '(internal) Visual Basic file limitation', 'description  This sample appears to be compiled from Visual Basic.',
          'representation called P-Code.', 'capa cannot handle Visual Basic executables well. This means that the results will be misleading or incomplete.',
          'You may have to analyze the file manually, for example using a tool like VB Decompiler.',
          'persist via Run registry key', 'packed with pebundle', 'capa cannot handle obfuscation well. This means the results may be misleading or incomplete.']

filename = 'Backdoor.Win32.BlackHole.asva_e7e4.exe' 
csv_file = '/home/zakaria/code/features.csv'
path_to_file = f'/home/zakaria/code/malware/{filename}'
result_list = [] # things i need to add

with open("output.txt", "w") as output_file: # opens the file
    subprocess.run(['./capa', '-v', path_to_file], stdout=output_file) # writes output to txt file

with open ('output.txt' , 'r') as raw_file:
    file_details = [line.strip() for line in raw_file]
for line in file_details:
    if line not in (value in line for value in values):
        result_list.append(line)

print(result_list)
```

Comment: [https://www.online-python.com/bM6QjBSRCe](https://www.online-python.com/bM6QjBSRCe)

Answer (score 2):

Avoid redundant `for` loop and check if a line contains any of `values` (with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) function):

```
with open ('output.txt' , 'r') as raw_file:
    result_list = [line_ for line in raw_file
                   if (line_ := line.strip()) and not any(v in line_ for v in values)]
    print(result_list)
```

---

```
['decompress data using aPLib', 'description  detects decompression function of library aPLib']
```